# Meteor JS Cannot read property of undefiend

Tags: javascript, excel, meteor

I'm trying to add new library to Meteor project but without successes. For example, I've found a library [for Excel export](https://atmospherejs.com/rpgeeganage/excel-builder) and added it with

```
meteor add rpgeeganage:excel-builder
```

and used it in js like here (action on button click)

```
Template.exportButton.events({
    "click #exportButton": function () {
        var workSheet = ExcelBuilder.createWorkbook('./', 'sample.xlsx');     
    }
});
```

but in brower console I'm getting

```
Cannot read property 'createWorkbook' of undefined
```

I have the same problem with other, similar libraries. How to make Meteor work with those libraries?

Comment: Do you import the package in your code? (for instance `import { ExcelBuilder } from 'excel-builder'; `)

Comment: Someone told me that after using meteor add x it should work without imports and similar things. But it don't. When I'm putting import ... on top of my js file I'm getting "While building the application:
webapp.js:163:13: Unexpected reserved word". Putting  <script type="text/javascript" src="rpgeeganage_excel-builder.js" ></script> in html does not work either.

Comment: It might be available on the server side only. Try creating a method on the server and calling it from the client.

Comment: It *is* available on the server only. See [the source](https://github.com/rpgeeganage/msexcelBuilder/blob/master/excel-builder/package.js#L15).